# How can I put an icon (favicon) in the browser tab of a website using webpack?

Tags: html, webpack, icons, webpack-dev-server, favicon

I am working with webpack (it is my first time) and so far I have not had problems, but when I try to put the icon does not work, I have tried many things and I do not know why it does not work.

I've dealt with jpg formats, ico and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Some of the  tags I've tried with are these:

```html
<link rel="icon" href="./../Icons/name-icon.ico" />
  
<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="./../Icons/name-icon.png" />
    
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="./../Icons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use HTML Webpack Plugin:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash].js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build')
  },
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: [path-to-html],
    favicon: [path-to-favicon],
    publicPath: './'
  })
};
```

Mention public path like this. But do not give `./` for any js or css output filenames in the webpack config.

Answer (score 0):

### follow this steps:

- in the head add `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />`
- make sure that `favicon.ico` file in the root [ in the same level of src ]
- if it dosen't work `Hard reload your browser`

if you changed distention path using any plugins like `copy-webpack-plugin` make sure to update your `href='new path'`

---

### another solution :

to use a plugin call `favicons-webpack-plugin-2`

it looks great it generate favicons and inject it

https://www.npmjs.com/package/favicons-webpack-plugin-2

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work without the use of webpack by adding the following **link** tag to my `index.html`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Folder structure:

```
public/
      images/
            favicon.ico
      index.html
```